# VSCode auto deleting the files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen a strange issue this morning,  VScode auto-deleted all my files, the folders are intact but the files inside all the subfolders are deleted. I have noticed there were some issues reported earlier, but has anyone seen this issue recently, any fix?

VSCODE version:  1.80.1
Windows 11

I was running a Python test, the files got deleted during the test as some tests were stopped in the middle for missing files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQmQL.png)

Comment: This kind of issues are most likely not related with vscode. Take a deeper look into scripts, extensions or other third party programs.

Comment: please give us an exact procedure to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: I've been using a few extensions for more than 3 years, and I've only updated Python 3.9 to Python 3.11 (32-bit) and Visual Studio to the latest version. Everything else remains the same. It is not possible for me to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue and the only way it would go away is to completely quit vscode and reopen it